# Google Cast for iOS v3: Initializing causing app to hang on launch

Tags: ios, google-cast

Using the v3.3 Google Cast SDK for iOS it now requires (as of v3 onwards) that you initialize it on app launch, on the main thread and as the app is launching. Let's put aside the fact that this seems like a terrible decision to make in terms of integrating this as a third party library.

The issue we're having is that every now and again this will cause our entire app launch to hang. Putting the phone into Airplane mode and relaunching fixes the issue. I don't have any logs available (though I'm looking for some to pass on). Has anyone else had this issue? Is there any workaround for it? Also are there plans to change the way this API works so that like every other third party app out there we can choose when and how it gets started and stopped? I get the convenience of hooking into app launch from an ease of use perspective, but I'm not a fan of the added launch time and possible issues like this.

Comment: Can you profile the app with Instruments? The GCKDeviceScanner is called asynchronous so it should not slow down the main thread.

Comment: I have the same issue. You don't need to initialize any kind of code from the GoogleCast Framework. Embedding it to your project seem to be enough to prevent your app from launching. 

Here is what I get from the debug console:

`2017-04-12 12:19:46.914 MyApp[1330:566007] GoogleCast framework version 3.3.0.11401

2017-04-12 12:19:46.919 MyApp[1330:566007] Starting diagnostic port

2017-04-12 12:19:46.920 MyApp[1330:566007] Start Listening on Port 2345, serverSocket: <GCKNTCPServerSocket: 0x1740b36e0>`

Comment: I just updated to SDK version 3.4.0. The bug seems to be fixed. I didn't notice any issues during launch.

Comment: Agreed with @Sven here — I had major memory bloat issues on launch with v3.3, so much that development on my app became untenable when tethered to Xcode. After updating to 3.4.0, I can verify I no longer have these issues.